# My click on DIV is not getting triggered

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="SubMenu"><ul><li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li></ul></div>
```

Now I wanted to fire a function when i click on div which has class "SubMenu" but the problem is i wanted to see if i have clicked there, i do not want to do like $(.'SubMenu').hide() instead i wanted to check that where i have clicked has a class SubMenu or not.

Issue here is i am not getting the element arrt dont know whats wrong, please help

Comment: Can you post your jquery code too please?

Comment: please provide your current javascript-code, so we can hunt down the bug :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hasClass` to check if an element has a particular class.

```
$('div').click( function() {
      alert( $(this).hasClass('SubMenu') );
});

// outputs true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. I assume that you are looking to hide a menu on document click. If you are after this you can do something like this

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('submenu'))
        {
            $('div.submenu').hide();    
        }
    });
    $("div.submenu").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // stops calling document click
    });
});
```